# Big Commerce: Insert Homepage Carousel on another page

Tags: carousel, bigcommerce

I'm looking to add the homepage slider to a different page. So what I did was create a page called 'Homepage', set it as the homepage, and call a custom snippet so that I can use the {{{page.content}}} from that page on the homepage.

Problem is, when doing that, the carousel does not work when calling this:

```
{{#if carousel.slides.length}}
  {{> components/carousel}}
{{/if}}
```

It seems that it doesn't see the carousel.slides.length.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, I figured it out.

You can use YAML / Front Matter
https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/using-yaml-front-matter#syntax

in my page.html file, I added this to the top:

```
{{# if page.title "==" 'Homepage'}}
  ---
  carousel: true
  products:
    featured:
      limit: {{theme_settings.homepage-show-featured-products}}
    new:
      limit: {{theme_settings.homepage-show-new-products}}
  ---
{{/if}}
```

What that achieves is when the Homepage page loads, it puts that at the top which adds carousel functionality.